# Google Drive Api: I get a positive response when trying to remove a permission but the permission hasn’t been removed

Tags: google-drive-api

I've got a similar to [this one](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3728&q=API%3DDrive%20permissions&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20API%20Owner), but no solution has been given.

I'm working on a `python` script that will tidy up a company `GoogleDrive`. 
The problem that I have is that when removing a user from our domain the shared files still have that user permission on them.

We can manually delete them but ideally we'd like a script to do it.

But when using `permissions().delete()` the permission is still there and I do not receive any error.

I tried using the `Try it!` on the Google Drive Api reference but same thing got a positive response (204) but permission wasn’t removed.

Note that when a user has been deleted the permission on the drive with `permissions.list()` show empty domain, email, and name but the rest (role, type, id, etag ...) still show.

Comment: You may need to post your code implementation on how exactly how you're doing it.

Comment: No sorry I haven't retried since then and I couldn't find any solution.